# read and execute ruby script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, process, jruby

**script.rb**:

```
puts 'hello'
puts 'foo'
```

**main.rb**:

```
puts `jruby script.rb` # receive the expected result
```

The question:
How can the same be achieved with reading the "script" before execution?

**main.rb**:

```
code=File.open('script.rb', 'r').read.gsub('"', '\"')
# puts `jruby -e '#{code}'` # Does not work for relatively big files;
```

Windows and unicode are the reasons of this question;

Please note that `` `jruby script.rb' `` creates a new process which is essential.

Comment: is main.rb run by jruby or ruby?

Comment: @PriteshJ, `jruby main.rb`

Comment: I was wondering why jruby --eval code is used and not directly eval(code)

Comment: also please specify what platform are you facing this issue on windows  or linux regarding unicode

Comment: @PriteshJ, "not directly eval(code)" -- one wouldn't create a new process, not sure whether there are other benefits; 
With all respect, I've already specified win os;

Comment: @ted *"Windows and unicode are the reasons of this question"* - could you elaborate?

Comment: ``ruby -e "#{code}"`` may well work (in backticks)

Comment: @Stefan, Dir.mkdir_p 'd:/tmp/اعببابب', put somefile.rb inside. Open cmd: `cd d`, `jruby 'd:/tmp/اعببابب'`. Or try to run that script from the other script outside that unicode name foler

Answer (score 1):

Store the modified script in a [Tempfile](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html) and run that instead of passing the whole contents as an eval argument:

```
require 'tempfile'

code = IO.read('script.rb').gsub('"', '\"')

begin
  tempfile = Tempfile.new 'mytempfile'
  f.write code
  f.close
  puts `jruby '#{f.path}'`
ensure
  f.close
  f.unlink
end
```

The reason you’re likely getting an error is either a lack of proper escaping or a limit on the maximum argument length in the shell.

Also, beware that in your original implementation you never close the original file. I’ve fixed that by instead using [`IO.read`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-c-read).

Comment: the problem is in running script from file, even from tmp dir; That's why I'm looking for a option to execute the script when file has been read. This will solve all the problem ` `jruby IO.read('script.rb')` ` (read and exec)

Comment: @ted you should state your actual problem in your question then, instead of a problem with your hacky solution to the real problem.

Comment: agreed partially; Still my solution may be hacky, the question states:  read and eval code instead of exec the script file. Dunno what's unclear, regards.

Comment: @ted My point is that you’re only trying to do that because of some other problem, it seems.

Comment: mostly, besides the matter of simply interest. I've been thinking that the file should be read in any case in order to be executed... but nvm

Answer (score 1):

In the command line, using

```
$ getconf ARG_MAX
```

will give the upper limit on how many bytes can be used for the command line argument and environment variables.

@Andrew Marshall's answer is better, but suppose you don't want to use a temp file, and assuming we can use [fork in JRuby](http://blog.headius.com/2009/05/fork-and-exec-on-jvm-jruby-to-rescue.html),

```
require 'ffi'
module Exec
  extend FFI::Library
  ffi_lib FFI::Platform::LIBC
  attach_function :fork, [], :int
end

code = IO.read('script.rb')
pid = Exec.fork
if 0 == pid
  eval code
  exit 0
else
  Process.waitpid pid
end
```

Comment: Pretty interesting solution. I'm even afraid to use it (: http://blog.headius.com/2009/05/fork-and-exec-on-jvm-jruby-to-rescue.html (update section). "Spoon" for a save fork solution https://gist.github.com/headius/321084

Comment: Spoon certainly looks safer, but I think it still requires a temp file.

Answer (score 0):

use require

**main.rb:**

```
require "script.rb"
```

Comment: will this create a new process while evaluating the script and return the output result as a string?..